# Чем нужно дополнить код

Tags: c++, c

Программа выполняющая сортировку двух массивов,первый-методом вставок,второй-методом пузырька,сортировку я провел,но надо сделать поэтапный вывод сортировки,за этап считается любое изменение элемента своего место положения,что нужно доставить и куда?

Код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
    int N = 9;
    int a[N];

    int buff = 0;   // для хранения перемещаемого значения
    int i, j,b;     // для цикла        
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Программа заполняющая массив случайными девятью числами в диапозоне от 60 до 80");
    printf("\nСортировка полученного массива методом Встановок");
    printf("\nЗаполнение второго массива из девяти чисел числами из диапозона от 60 до 80");
    printf("\nСортировка его методом пузырька\n\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        a[i] = 60 + rand() % 20;

    puts("Массив 1 имеет вид:");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%3d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    /************* Начало сортировки *******************/
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        buff = a[i]; // запомним обрабатываемый элемент
        // и начнем перемещение эдементов слева от него
        // пока заполненный не окажется меньше чем перемещаемый
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && a[j] > buff; j--)
            a[j + 1] = a[j];
            printf("Этапы сортировки:\n");
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
            printf("%3d", a[i]);
            putchar('\n');
            a[j + 1] = buff; // и поставим заполненный на его новое место   
    }
    /************* Конец сортировки *******************/
    printf("\nОтсортированный массив методом вставки имеет вид: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) // вывод  отсортированныго масс
    printf("%3d", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    /************* Вторая сортировака *******************/
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        a[i] = 60 + rand() % 21;
    printf("\n\n");
    puts("Массив 2 имеет вид:");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%3d", a[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < N-1; i++ )//сортировка пузырьком
    {
        for(j = 0; j < N-i-1; j++)
        {
            if(a[j] > a[j+1])
            {
                b = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];

                a[j+1] = b;
                for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    printf("%3d", a[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    printf("\nОтсортированный массив методом пузырька имеет вид: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    printf("%3d", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы же вроде это сделали (если не учесть неправильную сортировку), просто скобки не поставили куда нужно, чтобы выполнить в теле циклов.

Comment: Я сделал сортировку где есть начальный массив без сортировки и конечный отсортированный,а нужно добавить все этапы между  этими двумя массивами

Comment: В вашем коде нужно исправлять очень многое,  начиная с тогоо, что размер массива  'N '  должен быть определен константным.  Я вам посоветую сначала убрать все ваши выводы(думаю они вам больше мешают разобраться, чем помогают), написать правильный код, а после только добавлять  все  принты. И для всех циклов ставльте скобки, чтобы было ясно где заканчивается цикл.

Comment: Спасибо,буду пробовать